# Binary parameters to OData calls from within SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am implementing a function import call from within a SAPUI5 project and am trying to send a compressed and encoded string (i.e. as binary data) as part of the parameters to this function import:

```
oDataModel.callFunction("/myFunctionImport", {
  method: "POST",
  urlParameters: {
    SubmissionID: 1,
    JSONzip: sBase64Data
},

success: function (oData, oResponse) {
   // ...
},

error: function (oError) {
   // ... }
});
```

where "sBase64Data" is the compressed and encoded JSON string. The gateway is correctly set up so that the parameter types to the function import are set as an Edm.Int32 and Edm.Binary, respectively.

I keep getting a "Malformed URI literal syntax" error when I run this code. Any ideas of how I can directly send a binary parameter through to a function import call?

I am using the OData version 2.0.

Comment: what does the actual URL look like when making the call?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to send your data as urlParameter and not in the POST body?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Base64 is URL safe, because it allows `+`, `=` and `/`. I'm not sure about + and = but the `/` at least will mess with a URL because it's the separator.

try running the base64 encoded string through the standard function `encodeURIComponent`. It will translate all `/` to `%2F`, all `+` to `%2B` and all `=` to `%3D`.